# C++ does not name a type

Tags: c++

creating some old data structures in C++. Currently I am having an issue with a doubly-linked list class:

List.h:

```
template <class T>
class List{

private:

int size;

struct listNode{                        
    T data;
    listNode* next;
    listNode* prev;
    listNode(T newData);
};

listNode * head;                    
listNode * tail;                    
listNode * curr;                    
listNode * find(listNode * place, int k);   
void removeCurrent(listNode * temp);    
public:

List(); 
int getSize() const;                
void insert(int loc, T data);       
void remove(int loc);           
T const & getItem(int loc) const;   
void print();
```

};

List.cpp:

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
List<T>::List(){
size = 0;
head->next = tail;
head->prev = NULL;
tail->prev = head;
tail->next = NULL;


 }

// getSize: public method that returns the size of the list
template<class T>
int List<T>::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

// insert: public method that inserts data into the list
template<class T>
void List<T>::insert(int loc, T data){
    if(loc <1){
        cout<<"Invalid Location"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    curr = find(head,loc-1);
    listNode * newNode = new listNode(data);
    newNode->next = curr->next;
    newNode->prev = curr;
    newNode->next->prev = newNode;
    curr->next = newNode;
    size++;
}

// remove: public method that inserts data into the list
template<class T>
void List<T>::remove(int loc){
    if(loc <1){
        cout<<"Invalid Location"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    curr = find(head,loc);  // Find the node infront of the target
    removeCurrent(curr);    // Remove that node
}

// removeCurrent: helper function that removes the current node
template<class T>
void List<T>::removeCurrent(listNode* temp){
    listNode* t = temp->next;
    temp->data = t->data;       // HACK: take data from next node
    temp->next = t->next;
    t->next->prev = temp;
    delete t;
    t=NULL;
    size--;
}

// find: private helper function that returns a pointer to the k-1 node
template<class T>
listNode * List<T>::find(listNode * place, int k){
    if((k==0) || (place==NULL))
        return place;
    else return find(place->next,k-1);
}

// getItem: returns data at location loc
template<class T>
T const& List<T>::getItem(int loc) const{
    curr = find(head,loc);
    return curr->data;
}

// print: prints the sequence of variables in the list
template<class T>
void List<T>::print()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr->next != tail){
        curr = curr->next;
        cout<<curr->data<<endl;
    }
}

//listNode constructor
template<class T>
List<T>::listNode::listNode(T newdata):data(newdata),next(NULL),prev(NULL)
{}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

> error: 'listNode' does not name a type.

I have tried different suggestions offered in similar troubleshooting posts, but I'm still getting this error. I have a main.cpp that includes List.cpp, but it's practically empty.

Comment: Since you defined struct listNode within class List, its type is List<T>::listNode.

Comment: At witch line is the error?

Comment: cli_hlt has hit nail on the head - you have declared the listNode inside a class, so it needs to be prefixed with the class-name.

Comment: And you can `typedef List<T>::listNode listNode_t` and use the last one across whole class

Comment: You shouldn't place template class implementations in a separate module, that won't work anyway. The implementation needs to be seen when the template class is used (instantiated) elsewhere.

Comment: You souldn't include "List.cpp" but "List.h" in your main.cpp file.

Comment: More to the point, there shouldn't be (ideally) a `List.cpp` **at all.**

Comment: Why shouldn't there be a List.cpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to specify which `listNode` you're talking about at the `find` method's return type because you defined it as a member of the `List` class and you're also going to have to use `typename` (because `List<T>` is a dependent scope).

```
template <class T>
typename List<T>::listNode* List<T>::find(listNode* place, int k)
{
    if ((k == 0) || (place == NULL))
        return place;
    else
        return find(place->next, k-1);
}
```

Assuming you're using c++11, you may also want to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` since its safer and use the initializer list at the `List` constructor.

Comment: Not using C++11 yet--I'm a bit behind the times, but this worked! Thanks so much!